# CloudFlare dashboards empty, or performance issues

Tags: performance, cdn, cloudflare

I wanted to test CloudFlare performance so I set my image gallery domain on it and started testing. I have added PageRules for caching. And chose the Security: Essentially Off.
I checked NS check tools and they say that my domain name is propagated with CloudFlare.

For testing purpose I created a link that loads 200 images from that server, and was using loads.in website to determine how much it is faster.

After trying few regions, I noticed that there were no improvement in loading speed.

So I looked up the dashboards, and it was empty. I am not sure if I am doing something wrong, or made some error in my setup, or it takes few days to start caching or working properly, but at the moment - after a day of testing - dashboards are empty. Also the NS check tools sais that all name servers are propagated to CloudFlare and working fine.

So I assume I got a bad performance because it is simply not working.

I sent a letter to CloudFlare support team, but did not get any straight answer.

So essentially my question is:

Anyone has any experience with CloudFlare ? How long does it take for it to start caching static content to CDN ? Or there is simply something I am doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

Cloudflare's dashboard only updates once every 24 hours for free accounts, this is decreased if you upgrade. If you have waited for longer than that something is certainly wrong. Also I'd recommend doing a traceroute to your domain to see if it resolves to a Cloudflare IP.